# EC2 as a full-time VPS for Windows

Tags: hosting, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, shared-hosting, vps

I've been using Amazon EC2 for hosting a recently released website, mainly to gauge traffic demands etc. before committing to a more dedicated host. I'm currently using a small instance of Win2k8+SQL and paying about $80/month for the service.

Now that the site has been up for a month I am considering more long-term VPS solutions. However, I'm a bit surprised at costs. I don't see a significant price difference between EC2 and a dedicated VPS (usually a $20 difference for a similar level of equipment). I'm also a bit concerned, because some of the links posted here for VPS recommendations don't seem to work any more (ie. I'm confident Amazon will remain next year, but it seems that's not that case for all VPSes).

My questions:

1. Does anyone use EC2 for full-time, dedicated hosting of a Windows server, and is there any reason not to do so? I'm specifically noting that EC2 is a cloud provider for on-demand, transient loads, hence my curiosity about its suitability as a dedicated provider.
2. Are there any Windows VPSes that are recommended, have been in business for some time and do offer a cost benefit to just running on EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have multiple EC2 servers running commercial production websites, and I'm very satisfied with the price/performance ratio and general quality/stability.

The main reason I might look elsewhere would be for better/cheaper support...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that EC2 will be expensive in the long run. Also, it's a bit surprising that you cannot find any VPS provider that is at least half the cost. Most in the first couple of pages in a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+vps&oq=windows+vps&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are much cheaper for a similar config...

I use ZerOne Hosting and two of their (starter) [Windows VPS](http://zeronehosting.com/windows-vps/) plans for a couple of clients and been very satisfied. Uptime is almost perfect (except from the occasional maintenance) and since they use SSD for storage the VPS is very fast too. They also provide backups and on demand restores. Used it once just to check if it's indeed working and it did, they restored the VPS to an earlier backup with no issues. Of course it's not a cloud so you'll be missing some EC2 features but on the other hand this is the reason EC2 is expensive...

Answer (score 0):

There are issues, for instance last time I checked you couldn't configure RDNS.

The other problem is that if you start to make use of more than just the EC2 service your costs start to spiral. It is a fairly safe bet that a website will want to make use of EC2, S3, possibly RDS and also possibly ABS.

Comment: RDNS is generally only a big issue with email servers (in my experience).  Which brings up an important point:  EC2 is a TERRIBLE place to host an email server for a variety of reason (see numerous AWS forum posts on email pains).